# Need to run a pl/pgsql fn that runs an INSERT

Tags: function, postgresql, database-design, plpgsql, sql-insert

Here is what I have, I am trying to create an insert fn that loads row data essentially into a per-existing table. I also want to run a check on specific column data to make sure the source data is not invalid.

The problem I seem to be having is getting it to run successfully. For some reason I can't seem to get this to work and I have tried various ways and have researched diligently within the site(some that are close but, don't quite give me what I need). Here is basically what I have and want to achieve. I know it may be basic, so thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Schema.insert_fn (arg_1 character varying , arg_2 integer)
  RETURNS SETOF CHARACTER VARYING AS

$BODY$

BEGIN

--should this insert use some kind of temp table? 
     insert into <schema>.table1 (character varying, integer)
values (arg_1 character varying, arg_2 integer);

--If I wanted to run some sort of check on say arg_2
     If(select distinct (arg_2) from <schema>.table2 where invalid_date is not null)
     THEN
     raise notice 'Data has been invalidated';
END IF;
Return 'complete';
END;
$BODY$
```

**Update**

First, it told me that my return need to have 'NEXT' or 'QUERY'

> ```
>     RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set; 
>     use RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY at or near "'complete'"
> ```

Once I do this, of course the function will complete. However, when I call it I get an error saying for example:

> ```
>     invalid input syntax for type boolean: "arg_1"
> ```

I apologize if I come off a little vague. Obviously I can't give you the complete context of the arg names as they relate to what I am doing. I appreciate any help.

**Update**

I also receive this error:

> ```
>     more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> ```

I did research on this issue as well and simply cannot relate any kind of solution to at least get this to work, meaning; when I call it say, with no arguments I receive this error.

**Update** @ErwinBrandstetter. I communicated that wrong. I meant if

```
    'col2 = arg_2 and invalid_date is NOT null' to raise an exception
```

What is happening is that the 'EXIST' statement will take any instance to where a row is found. I tried 'WHERE EXIST' and I got an error. The problem I figure is that they(validated and invalidated data) share the same unique id whether and it makes the EXIST statement true(I didn't provide this info mind you).

**Update**
@ErwinBrandstetter It now operates successfully. Looks like all I needed to do was seperate the two conditions. Thanks.

```
    IF EXISTS (condition)
    THEN
    INSERT

    ELSEIF EXISTS (invalidated data condition)
    THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION'DATA IS INVALIDATED';
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: "getting it to run successfully" is a little vague. Can you be more specific? What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: I have had several iterations of this each with their own unique issues.

Comment: First, it told me that my return need to have 'NEXT' or 'QUERY'
    
    RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set; 
    use RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY at or near "'complete'"

Once I do this, of course the fn will complete. However, when I call it I get an error saying for example:

    invalid input syntax for type boolean: "arg_1"

I apologize if I come off a little vague. Obviously I can't give you the complete context of the arg names as they relate to what I am doing. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.insert_fn (_arg1 text, _arg2 integer)
  RETURNS text AS  -- not SETOF!
$func$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO <schema>.table1 (col1, col2)  -- names here! not types
SELECT _arg1, _arg2                       -- again: names! cast only if needed
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (                       -- only if _arg2 not invalidated
   SELECT 1
   FROM   <schema>.table2
   WHERE  col2 = _arg2
   AND    invalid_date IS NOT NULL
   );

IF NOT FOUND THEN  -- No exception yet, no INSERT either --> invalidated
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Data >>%<< has been invalidated.', _arg2;
END IF;

RETURN 'complete'::text;  -- return value probably useless

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The most prominent error was that you declared the function to return a `SETOF` values, while you actually only return a single value. I might just use `RETURNs void`, since the return value does not carry information as is.
Read the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

Use a `SELECT` with your `INSERT` to apply additional conditions directly.

There is more. See comments in code above.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter. It does run in a sense but, I wanted to be able to run a check on arg_2, and if it is 'invalidated' to 'raise an exception'. What you gave me does work. I tried using where 'col2 = arg_2 and invalid_date is null' but, that only completes the insert and I don't want it to do that if the 'invalid_date is null'.

So I put the insert into the 'ELSE' statement so I figured that would work but, it is more of the same. It completes and it gives me the comment of 'Data has been invalidated'